# し grammarの使い方を教えてください

Tags: particle-し

‎どうして、
「広いし家賃が安い家を探してます。」は間違いで、「広くて家賃が安い家を探しています。」
が正しいんですか。

Answer (score 1):

I think し is used to join two separate clauses. In your example you're trying to use it to join two things that both modify 家 in a single clause. So your sentence would read "It's spacious, and I'm looking for a house with cheap rent", which doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: 分かったと思います。それではこう言ったら、1)「ナタリさんはかわいいし、性格がいいです。」と言えますが、2)「かわいいし、性格がいいナタリさん」と言えないんでしょうか。

Comment: 「ナタリーさんはかわいいし、性格もいいです。」「かわいいし、性格もいいナタリーさん」って言うといいと思います。

Comment: @Chocolate Given your comment, I guess my answer is wrong. Does that mean the OP's original  sentence is fine, or is there another explanation?

Comment: @user3856370 Your answer is basically correct. I'm wondering how to explain too, but anyway, 広いし家賃が/も安い家を… is definitely wrong. Using it in 体言止め feels somehow marginal, but it's still (technically?) wrong, I think.

Comment: I noticed that Chocolate's sentence is of the form し＋も, while the first sample sentence isn't. Would it be correct if changed to 「広いし家賃も安い家」?

Comment: @DXV I didn't notice that, but now we're scanning the fine detail it turns out that user4092 explicitly ruled that out in his comment.